# How to get user info from Sentry scope when capturing exception or message

Tags: javascript, sentry

If I want to capture a Sentry message and include the user info set on the Sentry scope, how can I do that?

For example if I'm setting the user ID to the scope

```
Sentry.configureScope(scope => scope.setUser({ id: '123' }))
```

Then later if I want to send a Sentry message like `"User 123 could not send message 456"`

```
Sentry.captureMessage(`User ${userId} could not send message ${messageId}`)
```

I can get the message ID from the surrounding code but how do I access the `user.id` that I set on the scope in this context?

Answer (score 0):

By accessing [Sentry scope](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/enriching-events/context/), you can get info like the `user` or anything else already configured to the Sentry scope.

The example to get the user ID would be to use [Sentry local scopes](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/enriching-events/scopes/#local-scopes) like this

```
Sentry.withScope(scope => {
  const user = scope.getUser()
  Sentry.captureMessage(
    `User ${user.id} could not send message ${messageId}`
  )
})
```

However, this type of message would probably create a lot of unique messages which would probably create a lot of noise. Perhaps consider an alternative approach where the message itself can be consistent and informative while the event-specific info is added as Sentry context or tags.

For example:

```
Sentry.withScope(scope => {
  scope.setTag('messageId', messageId)
  // The user info and user.id is already part of the context in Sentry
  // const user = scope.getUser()
  Sentry.captureMessage(
    `User could not send message`
  )
})
```

This way, all similar occurrences will be "stacked" into one entry in Sentry and you can always click into it to expand and search by the tags if desired, etc.